# Php pdo inserting firm with session data

Tags: php, forms, pdo, insert, session-variables

I am working on an application that has different forms that a logged in user can fill out and submit.  For example, an artist is able to submit their video through a form and that movie will be saved and uploaded to the database. 
However, I would like when a form is submitted for it to automatically connect the userID and userEmail to the form when it is submitted so that I can easily check for either user id or email when pulling back data. 
I have tried several different methods of doing this and nothing has worked so any help is much appreciated.  I am also using foreign keys in my database tables but I do not understand how that works in connecting to a table. 
So here is my table setup for users and for movies
Users table

```
       CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS.            `users` (
        `userID` int(11) NOT NULL.        AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `userEmail` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
         `userPass` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
         `userType` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
          `agreement` enum('Yes', 'No') NOT NULL,
        `userStatus` enum('Y','N') NOT NULL. DEFAULT 'N',
        `tokenCode` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
         PRIMARY KEY (`userID`),
          UNIQUE KEY `userEmail`    (`userEmail`)
        ) ENGINE= MyISAM DEFAULT.         CHARSET=latin1.        AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Movies Table

```
             CREATE TABLE `movies` (
             `userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
              `userEmail` varchar(250) NOT.     NULL,
              `movie_name` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
               FOREIGN KEY (userID)    Refrences users(userID),
               FOREIGN KEY (userEmail)   REFRENCES users(userEmail),
               UNIQUE KEY `movie_name` (`movie_name`)
               ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT.               CHARSET=latin1;
```

The Form page is here 
( I tried adding the SESSION data to the POST here and tried the GET method to add SESSION data neither of which worked)

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 $email = trim($_POST['email']);
 $movie = trim($_POST['movie']);

 if($user_home->upload($email,    $movie))
 {
  header("Location: Artist_Uploads.php?inserted");
 }
 else
 {
  header("Location: Artist_Uploads.php?failure");
 }
}

<form action="Artist_Uploads.php" method="post" name="upload">
<input name="email" type="hidden"   value="<?php echo.   htmlentities($row['userEmail']); ?>" />
<input name="movie" type="text" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Page that processes form submission

```
public function upload($email,$movie)      {   try

  {
  $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO  movies(userEmail, movie_name)     VALUES(:email, :movie)");
   $stmt->bindValue(":email",$email);  
   $stmt->bindparam(":movie",$movie);
   $stmt->execute();
   return true;
  }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
   echo $e->getMessage(); 
   return false;
  }

 }
```

I have tried insert lasted() below the return true and before the return true.
Tried adding VALUES ('','$_SESSION[cuserID]','$_SESSION[userEmail]','') :movies");. 
I also tried adding the _SESSION data in the bindValue or the bindCol neither of those worked either. 
 I also tried adding INSERT INTO movies FROM users.userID, users.userEmail but that did not work either.

So I do not know how to get it to insert the userID and userEmail without outputting it into the form then inserting it that way but that seems to dangerous and open to injection because someone could easily manipulate that info or 
get the users ID and start playing with it.  So any suggestions or pointers would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question using code blocks for the SQL and PHP as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for editing. As best I understand your code and explanation—and it's difficult to read—you're trying to get data out of `$_SESSION`. After the form is submitted, the data is in `$_POST`, not in `$_SESSION`. Otherwise, make sure you have error reporting turned on in PHP, and share any errors as part of the question.

Comment: I'd like to submit the session data with the form not after its submitted. Say a user is logged in and they would like to submit a movie. When they submit their movie their user ID and user email would automatically be saved to the database when form is submited. The session data has the user ID and email I'm just not sure how to get that info to attach when the user submits the form. Does that make more since?

Comment: The session data should already persist across pages (that's what `$_SESSION` does), so there is no reason to add it to your form. (Unless you have a security tool that checks nonces, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.)

Comment: Yes it persist across the pages.  When a user submits there movie I want to know in the database the user that submitted the movie.  I can add the php echo to the form to save that data but that does not seem secure becouse could be easily manipulated. So I'm trying to find a way to submit that info about the user into the database when the movie form is submited.

Answer (score 1):

The user ID or username whatever you use to **uniquely and permanently** identify each user should be stored in the session right after the user is authenticated. I say permanently because by using the email and then even setting up foreign key constraints on the email you are looking for a world of pain. Don't do that. Use something that would never be modified by the user. Typically users aren't allowed to modify their username and it would be pointless to give a user the option to modify their user id.

First you authenticate (something like this):

```
<?php

if ($user->authenticate($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $user->getUserId();
}
else {
    echo "invalid password";
}
```

On subsequent requests, make sure you do `session_start()` first, and then you can just retrieve the information from the database using the value stored in the session. No need to send it in the form. In fact, sending it in the form would be a huge security risk because people could upload videos to other users' accounts.

```
session_start();

// Make sure user is logged in
if (!isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
}

// Pull their info from the database
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = ?");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $_SESSION['userid']);
$stmt->execute();
$user = $stmt->fetch();
```

Then you can execute your other queries based on the values you get in `$user`. Similar to what I mentioned earlier, get rid of emails from tables where it is irrelevant. You are duplicating information across tables and modifying the value would be very difficult. You also want to add some sort of unique way to identify the movies as well:

```
CREATE TABLE `movies` (
    `movieID` int(11) NOT NULL.        AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `movie_name` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (userID)    Refrences users(userID),
    UNIQUE KEY `movie_name` (`movie_name`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT.               CHARSET=latin1;
```

Then query:

```
public function upload($userid,$movie)      {
    try
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO  movies(userID, movie_name)     
            VALUES(:userid, :movie)");
        $stmt->bindValue(":userid",$userid);  
        $stmt->bindparam(":movie",$movie);
        $stmt->execute();
        return true;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage(); 
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Looking closer at your code, you should probably also remove the unique key on `movie_name`. I don't see why two movies [couldn't contain the same name](http://www.andsoitbeginsfilms.com/2013/07/top-15-movies-with-same-title.html).

Comment: I do have the first part where they login and it checks them in database and saves the session info. I do not get the   part where you have stmt->bindValue(1, $_SESSION['userid']); what is the 1 from? Won't that depend on the user? Then in the second have how's it know what user ID to input if you just have userid.  I guess that's what's throwing me off I don't get how it knows the user ID if I don't tell it.

Comment: OK I did as you suggested and I get the following errors "missing argument 2 for user::upload called in for defined in functions " next error "undefined index user ID in functions"   also getting " integrity constraint violation movie name can not be null" I filled out for but still give that error.  Also I do have email as unique in the users table I see comments that I needs to be unique and it is.  I know some of those error are becomes the input of user ID is not in the form but I don't think it should be for security.

Comment: I think the error messages are pretty self-explanatory. If not, Google them. The code I have here is just an example, but variable names could change. You should never just copy and paste into your app. Try to understand *what* I have done and how does that differ from what you have and then adapt that to your app.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues going on here. I can't say I completely understand the errors you're seeing (please post any error messages as part of the question).

However, I do see a potentially significant issue with your table schema. If the `movies` table has `users.userID` as a foreign key, it should not need a `userEmail` attribute at all (nor its associated foreign key), as this information is obtained by joining `users` and `movies` on `userID`. In addition, trying to build a foreign key on `userEmail` is extra problematic, as `users.userEmail` is not guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: Email could very well be unique if you add a unique index to the table.

Comment: Could be designed that way. And probably should be. It wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

On the page that process the form do the following

```
   If (isset ($_POST ['submit']))
  {
 $email = $_SESSION ['userEmail'];
```

Everything else is normal and it works perfectly.  Just make sure you have sessions setup or it will not work.